# Instantiation of a custom class

Tags: unity, c#, gameobject

I have a custom class named Stars:

```
class Star
{
    public int primaryID;
    public string properName;
    public string HIPID;
    public string HDID;
    public string HRID; 
    public string GLID;
    public string BFID;
    public decimal rightAscension;
    public decimal declination;
    public string magnitude;
    public string colourIndex;
    public int scale;
    public int red;
    public int green;
    public int blue;
    public bool isSimulated;
    public double x;
    public double y;
    public double z;

    public void setDetails(int primaryID, string properName, string HIPID, string HDID, string HRID, string GLID, string BFID, decimal rightAscension, decimal declination, string magnitude, string colourIndex)
    {
        this.primaryID = primaryID;
        this.properName = properName;
        this.HIPID = HIPID;
        this.HDID = HDID;
        this.HRID = HRID;
        this.GLID = GLID;
        this.BFID = BFID;
        this.rightAscension = rightAscension;
        this.declination = declination;
        this.magnitude = magnitude;
        this.colourIndex = colourIndex;
        decimal deg2rad = 0.01745329251994329576923690768489m;

        this.isSimulated = true;

        // Decimal datatype is used to make sure that values are very accurate and precise
        decimal degrees_ra;
        decimal degrees_dec;
        decimal radians_ra;
        decimal radians_dec;

        degrees_ra = Decimal.Multiply(rightAscension, 15);
        degrees_dec = declination;

        radians_ra = Decimal.Multiply(degrees_ra, deg2rad);
        radians_dec = Decimal.Multiply(degrees_dec, deg2rad);

        // Converted from decimal to double because the Math library cannot work with decimals
        float distanceStars = 19113;

        this.x = (distanceStars * Math.Cos(decimal.ToDouble(radians_dec)) * Math.Cos(decimal.ToDouble(radians_ra)));
        this.y = (distanceStars * Math.Cos(decimal.ToDouble(radians_dec)) * Math.Sin(decimal.ToDouble(radians_ra)));
        this.z = (distanceStars * Math.Sin(decimal.ToDouble(radians_dec)));
    }

    public Vector3 getVector()
    {
        return new Vector3((float)z, (float)y, (float)x);
    }
}
```

There are many of these stars and I want to instantiate them at run-time:

```
void plotStars()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < (StarDataBank.Instance.NumOfStars))
    {
        string name = StarDataBank.Instance.StarName[i];
        string HIP = StarDataBank.Instance.StarIDHIP[i];
        string HD = StarDataBank.Instance.StarIDHD[i];
        string HR = StarDataBank.Instance.StarIDHR[i];
        string GL = StarDataBank.Instance.StarIDGL[i];
        string BF = StarDataBank.Instance.StarIDBF[i];
        decimal RA = Convert.ToDecimal(StarDataBank.Instance.StarRA[i]);
        decimal Dec = Convert.ToDecimal(StarDataBank.Instance.StarDec[i]);
        string Mag = StarDataBank.Instance.StarMag[i];
        string ColI = StarDataBank.Instance.StarCI[i];

        var star = new Star();
        star = Instantiate(ObjectStar, transform.position + star.getVector(), Quaternion.identity);

        star.transform.parent = StarObject.transform;
        star.transform.localScale = new Vector3(star.scale, star.scale, star.scale);
        i++;
    }
}
```

But I am experiencing a lot of errors.

1. Unity isn't instantiating the Stars because it can't convert UnityEngine.Transform to Star
2. Star doesn't contain definition of Transform

Is there a way to assign a class as a gameobject?

Comment: Did you mean to make Star a component you can attach to a `GameObject` by inheriting from `MonoBehaviour`? How is your `ObjectStar` variable defined and initialized?

Comment: ObjectStar is declared as public Transform ObjectStar; And a prefab has been attached to this through the unity editor

Comment: How do I attach this class as a gameobject? and will that allow me to instantiate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using the variable named `star` to do double-duty:

`var star = new Star();`

This says "make a new data structure to hold information about this star"

`star = Instantiate(ObjectStar, ...);`

This says "make a new copy of the `ObjectStar` game object to represent this star in the game scene, and give me its `Transform` (since the `ObjectStar` variable is of type `Transform`"

These two uses are contradictory. This variable cannot simultaneously hold a `Star` and a `Transform`. Pick one or the other.

So, use separate variables for these two uses:

```
Star star = new Star();
Transform sceneObject = Instantiate(ObjectStar, ...);`
```

If you want to associate information from this star data structure with your scene object, you have a few options:

- You can use a `Dictionary` to store a mapping from star data to scene objects, or vice versa
- You can make your `Star` class a `MonoBehaviour` component that can be attached to a game object, just like other components in Unity, using `AddComponent` in script, or the button at the bottom of the Inspector.
- You can make a new `MonoBehaviour` component to attach to your scene object, that holds a reference to a `Star` data structure. This lets you get the advantages of bolting the component directly to the object it relates to, while keeping your `Star` class uncluttered with `MonoBehaviour` stuff — in case your `Star` class needs to be serialized or inter-operate with non-Unity code elsewhere in your project.

Here's an example of that last style:

```
public class StarRepresentation : MonoBehaviour {
    public Star starData;
}
```

You can set up your `ObjectStar` object to have one of these `StarRepresentation` components attached, by using the "Add Component" button in the Inspector.

Then you can change your declaration of the object to...

```
public StarRepresentation starPrefab;
```

Making it use the `StarRepresentation` type means that when you `Instantiate` it, you'll get the component you want directly, without needing a `GetComponent` call.

Now when you want to instantiate & populate your new star object with star data, you can do it like this:

```
StarRepresentation representation = Instantiate(starPrefab, ...);
representation.starData = new Star ();
```

Then you can fill in the details of this `starData` as you like.